# When/how is the "memoryview()" function used?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, skip, enumerate

I came across it in my autocomplete when I started typing the name of a variable that began with `m`, what is it used for and when/how should it be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`memoryview()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/memoryview) exposes the buffer protocal of an object. Buffers are internal memory arrays. You can use `memoryview()` to access large pieces of data without having to copy the data, which can be memory-intensive.

Edit: To further explain, when you know the memory address of an object, you can simply set another object equal to that memory address